# Does MAX(expr) have a limit

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with 25,000 entries and growing. In the code, there is this line

```
$result = sqlQuery("SELECT MAX(pid)+1 AS pid FROM patient_data");
$newpid = 1;

if ($result['pid'] > 1) $newpid = $result['pid'];
```

This line returns an error from the database that says duplicate record at 10000.

What this line of code is supposed to be doing is to retrieve the last entry for the pid column and then the next lines of code add one to create the next entry in the table.

From my research MAX() is a summing tool, not a tool used to retrieve the last value entered into a table. 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max

Looking for some clarification on how to use this properly. I can't seem to find a clear answer. Hoping some you more experienced developers can help steer me in the right direction.

Comment: `summing tool`? And what does it sums?

Comment: Auto-increment generates the next number for you. No need for such things. Take a good SQL tutorial.

Comment: Please be careful. You are trying to use a method for assigning `id` values that's notorious for working correctly during development and test, then failing -- with user data loss -- in production. Because: race conditions.  Please [edit] your question to present the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE patient_data`, then pay attention to the answers you get.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. This app was built way before me and I am just trying to keep it working. We can fit things on the rewrite of the program.

Answer (score 0):

Since the table already has the ID column auto incremented and there is only one of those allowed per table in MySQL. I had to resort to a different method.

Decided to go with the get the last record this way.

```
$result = sqlQuery("SELECT id AS pid FROM patient_data ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
$newpid = 1;

if ($result['pid'] > 1) $newpid = $result['pid'] + 1; //Changed by Sherwin

setpid($newpid);
```